# MINECRAFT: Is there a way of blocking messages incoming from a plugin?

Tags: java, minecraft

I am pretty new to Java. I learned a lot this month by making Minecraft plugins and I'd like to try making a new type of plugin:

a plugin that blocks messages incoming from another plugin if them contain a certain word or sentence.

How can I achieve that? I'm asking this because there are lot of plugins with hardcoded messages and people who don't know how to code cannot change them. I am making some addon plugins for many other plugins to help people customizing messages. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. You should intercept the message you don't want using packet handling.

You can do it directly from the `Bukkit` server or on the `Bungeecord` proxy layer.

To make things easy, you can use `ProtocolLib`. I've not been working with Minecraft for a long time, I'm not sure how different will be that library but I let you here a piece of code to let you search on it.

```java
ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager().addPacketListener(
    new PacketAdapter(this, ConnectionSide.SERVER_SIDE, Packets.Server.CHAT) {
        @Override
        public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {
            String message = event.getPacket().getStrings().read(0);
            event.getPacket().getStrings().write(0, "Intercepted: "+message);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and I will let you know.